# Session returns 0 for all users

Tags: php, session

I'm stuck on the register and login script, For some reason, my $user_id returns 0 no matter who I am logged in with. I have gone through the code over and over and for some reason the session seems to be not fetching the users id from the database.

I have had a look around and a few people have had this problem and their fixes, if any was given proved negative for me.

init.php

```
<?php

session_start();
//error_reporting(0);


require 'database/connect.php';
require 'functions/general.php';
require 'functions/users.php';

if (logged_in() === true) {
$session_user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$user_data = user_data($session_user_id, 'user_id', 'username', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email');

}

$errors = array();
?>
```

functions/users.php

```
<?php

function logged_in() {
return (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) ? true : false;
}

function user_data($user_id)
{
$data = array();
$user_id = (int)$user_id;

$func_num_args = func_num_args();
$func_get_args = func_get_args();

if($func_num_args > 0)
{
    unset($func_get_args[0]);
    $fields = '`' . implode('', $func_get_args) . '`';
    // check the query executed. mysql_query returns false if there is an     error
    if(($result = mysql_query("SELECT '".$fields."' FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = '".$user_id."'")) !== false)
    {
        // check that the query did actually return any results
        if(mysql_num_rows($result))
        {
            return mysql_fetch_assoc($result); // return the result
        }
        // query didn't return any results
        else
        {
            echo 'user_data() query returned no results!';
        }
    }
    // query has failed find out why using msyql_error();
    else
    {
        echo 'user_data() query has failed - ' . mysql_error();
    }
}
return false;
}


function user_exists($username) {
$username = sanitize($username);
return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '".$username."'"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}

function user_active($username) {
$username = sanitize($username);
return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '".$username."' AND `active` = 1"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}

function user_id_from_username($username) {
$username = sanitize($username);
return mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` =     '".$username."' AND `password` = '".$password."'"), 0, 'user_id');
}

function login($username, $password) {
$user_id = user_id_from_username($username);

$username = sanitize($username);
$password = MD5($password);

return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE    `username` = '".$username."' AND `password` = '".$password."'"), 0) == 1) ? '".$user_id."'     : false;
}
?>
```

login.php

```
<?php 

include 'core/init.php';

if (empty ($_POST) === false) {
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if (empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true) {
    $errors[] = 'You need to enter a username and or password';
    }else if (user_exists ($username) === false)  {
    $errors[] = 'Your username is not registered on our server. Have you <a          href = register.php> registered?</a>';
    }else if (user_active ($username) === false) {
    $errors [] = 'You need to activate your account!';
    }else {

        if (strlen($password) > 32) {
            $errors[] = 'password too long';
        }

        $login = login($username, $password);
        if ($login == false){
        $errors[] = 'Username or password is incorrect';
        } else {
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;
        header ('LOCATION: index.php');
        exit();
        }
    }


}else {
    $errors[] = 'no data';  
    }

include 'includes/overall/header.php';
if (empty($errors) === false) {
?>
<h2>We tried to log you in, BUT...</h2>

<?php
}
echo output_errors($errors);

include 'includes/overall/footer.php';
?>
```

If you know how to fix this, if you had the same issue, I would be so grateful! I've been pulling my hair out over this lol.

Thanks!

Comment: Please ensure that `session_start()` in your every script. as you have not started session in `functions/users.php` and `login.php`

Comment: do you get user values from database in users.php? or what that user_data function returns exactly?

Comment: Init.php is in included in every page, session_start(); is at the top of that page

Comment: First, you should put `unset($func_get_args[0]);` before `if($func_num_args > 0)` because you will have bugs one day. (i'm actually reading your code)

Comment: @hardy yes, it gets it from the functions in users.php

Comment: Can you clean your code and remove useless lines plz ?

Comment: @56ka sorry, I'm not a pro php developer. I'm not sure what you mean by useless lines lol.

Comment: @PrivateMufasa yes, i know that but what that function returns to you? real values you know.. what you get when you try to run your code :) "user_data() query returned no results!" or what?

Comment: Ok if you are not sure it does not matter, just keep it like this ;)

Comment: @hardy oh sorry. Function user_data, and yes, it says it returns no results. It's 9:30am, I've not slept at all lol

Comment: @56ka haha ok. I will tidy it up one when I get it all working lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
unset($func_get_args[0]);
$fields = '`' . implode('', $func_get_args) . '`';
// check the query executed. mysql_query returns false if there is an     error
if(($result = mysql_query("SELECT '".$fields."' FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = '".$user_id."'")) !== false)
{
    // check that the query did actually return any results
    if(mysql_num_rows($result))
    {
        return mysql_fetch_assoc($result); // return the result
    }
    // query didn't return any results
    else
    {
        echo 'user_data() query returned no results!';
    }
}
```

to this:

```
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT user_id, username, password, email FROM users WHERE user_id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($user_id)."'");

    if($query && mysql_num_rows($query))
    {
      return mysql_fetch_assoc($query); // return the result
    } else {
      // no results or error..
   }
```

Comment: That broke my script lol. Not even loading now. Maybe I pasted it wrong.

Comment: then there is something wrong in your fields.. try adding your fields manually to that sql clause.

Comment: user_data() query has failed - Unknown column 'user_id,username,password,email' in 'field list'

Comment: user_data() query has failed - Unknown column '' in 'field list' - all the fields have gone, but im still getting this error.

Comment: ok, You have some extra quote or empty field definition in your select clause.. try learning php and sql more.. this is getting hopeless :)

Comment: lol yeah, im getting frustrated with this. I think its referring to this: $user_data = user_data($session_user_id, `user_id`, `username`, `password`, `email`); -- in init.php. When i change it from ` to ' or remove both, it gives a different error.

Comment: why you are passing fields for that function? Why not just hardcode those fields like i showed..?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to apply some glue to your implosion:

```
$fields = implode(', ', $func_get_args);
```

That might fix *something*, at least. I don't have all your `require`'d files though, or your database schema, so I can't say for certain.

Comment: I have done this. Thanks for the suggestion. However, this has already been done after the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the login function

```
// WRONG
return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE    `username` = '".$username."' AND `password` = '".$password."'"), 0) == 1) ? '".$user_id."'     : false;
```

The mysql_query() function returns a resource, or false if there is failure or no results. Your assumption is that it returns 1.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytale WHERE somecondition");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

**NOTE**:
Your code is very badly written, because it is insecure, There are probably a few thousand warnings on SO itself asking people to refrain from getting login information like in your login query. Please update your query.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this now. This is just an experimental educational script, stepping stones, insecurity is not an issue for me at the moment, it's not going live.

Comment: @crafter: He has a `sanitize()` function at least. @PrivateMufasa: Read up when you get the chance: http://us1.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php

Comment: crafter is that causing the user_id to return 0? I can log in perfectly fine. @jackson thanks, I will take a loot :)

Comment: If you login details are correct, mysql_query will return some value not equal to 1, otherwise it will return false (or 0). Therefore, your login will always return 0, and therefore you always populate session with 0.

Comment: Interesting, ok, I'll take a look and change it.